# Table wrapped inside div container

Tags: html, css, containers, word-wrap, css-tables

I am trying to wrap a table inside a div container that has a specified length and width.

Currently I am having trouble wrapping the table inside of it.

**NOTE** I am using materialize.css for its CSS framework

I've set the container (**class.board**) with black border so visually I can explain it better

Here's what it looks like currently:

[image]

I am using React to render the html so forgive me for sending the screenshot instead:

[image]

**SCSS**

```
nav{
  background: skyblue;
}

body{
  background: #e2e2e2;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-collapse:collapse;
}

td{
  width: 33.33%;
  position: relative;
  color: #101935;
  background: #F2FDFF;
  border: 4px solid #DBCBD8;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background 0.4s ease-out;
}

td:hover{
  background: #564787;
}

.alive{
  background: #61baf2;
}

.btn{
  background: #93C0A4
}

.controller{
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.pause{
  background: #be3131;
}

.generation{
  background: #977fd0;
  cursor: default;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.board {
  border: solid 4px;
  height: 40px;

}
```

Ideally in my app, I wish to change nxn of the table and at the same time, wrapped under the div container.

I've played around for few hours on this, but have not come up with the solution yet.

Comment: Try adding overflow: hidden to the board class

Comment: That did the trick and I realize the materialize.css is adding padding inside the cells of the table.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `display: table;` in the css for `.board` class.